# For Lie groups $G$ and $H$, a homomorphism $f:G\rightarrow H$ is surjective if $f_*:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow\mathfrak{h}$ is surjective

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

We know that if $f:G\rightarrow H$ is a Lie group homomorphism, then the induced map $f_*:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow\mathfrak{h}$ of their Lie algebras is an algebra homomorphism. It follows relatively easily that if $f$ is furthermore an isomorphism, then so is $f_*$, although the converse does not hold - for instance, if $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is given by $a\mapsto a+\mathbb{Z}$, then this is not an isomorphism even though the Lie algebras of both sides are isomorphic (to $\mathbb{R}$).

But can we say anything in this reversed direction? In particular I am trying to prove that if $f_*$ is surjective then so is $f$ - I have made almost no progress proving this to be true but have been unable to find a counterexample. Any ideas?

Edit: forgot to mention I am considering all this under the assumption that both $G$ and $H$ are connected (although a comment below has made me realise perhaps only the latter is important).

Comment: What if $ H$ is not connected?

Comment: @user81327 thank you, please see my edit.

Comment: Then I think it is true. If $ H $ is compact and connected, then the exponential map $ \mathfrak{h} \rightarrow H $ is surjective.

Answer (score 8):

This holds if $H$ is connected. The fact that $f_{*}$ is onto guarantees that $f$ is surjective onto a neighborhood of the identity of $H$ and since a neighborhood of the identity of $H$ generates $H$ as a group and $f$ is a group homomorphism, we see that $f$ is surjective onto $H$.

Comment: Sorry for the late response - could you please be more clear on why $f_*$ being surjective implies $f$ is onto a neighbourhood of $e_H$? Is this just an application of the inverse/implicit function theorem?

Comment: @kt77: Yeah, although I prefer to think about it in terms of the constant rank theorem. Since $f_{*}$ is surjective, $f$ is a submersion near the identity $e$ of $G$ so it looks in terms of local coordinates as $(x_1,\dots,x_n) \mapsto (x_1,\dots,x_k)$ for $k \leq n$ so in particular it is onto a neighborhood of the identity of $H$.

Comment: Thanks that makes it clearer. As for the other part - a result in my notes says if $H$ is a connected topological group and $U\subset{H}$ is an open subset containing $e_H$, then $\cup_{n=0}^\infty U^n=H$. Thus any $h\in H$ can be written $h=u_1\dots u_n$ for some $u_i\in U$, and if we take $U$ as the set onto which $f$ is surjective, then each $u_i=f(g_i)$ for some $g_i\in G$ and so $h=u_1\dots u_n=f(g_1)\dots f(g_n)=f(g_1\dots g_n)$ as required?