# spin homomorphism $SL_2(\mathbb C)\to O(1,3)_e$

Tags: lie-groups, covering-spaces

I've shown that we have the following action of $SL_2(\mathbb C)$ on $\mathbb R^4$:
$$
\phi\colon SL_2(\mathbb C)\to O(1,3)
$$
given by
$$
\phi_X\colon W\mapsto XWX^\dagger.
$$
Since $SL_2(\mathbb C)$ is connected, and our homormophism is continuous, it follows that $\phi(SL_2(\mathbb C))$ is contained in the identity component $O(1,3)_e$. However, I would like to argue that it is equal to $O(1,3)_e$. How can I do that?

Comment: Is remark #21 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#The_covering_group_SL(2,_C)) relevant?

Comment: @Karl I'm not sure which remark you're referring to.

Comment: In the "remarks" section.

Comment: It depends on how much Lie theory you know, see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301289/spinor-mapping-is-surjective. A direct argument will be that the image of $\phi$ is an open subgroup, hence, closed, hence, is the entire $O(1,3)_e$. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240334/for-lie-groups-g-and-h-a-homomorphism-fg-rightarrow-h-is-surjective-if?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed.